# Calculating probability function

Tags: probability

Suppose that $15$% of the families dont have childs, $20$% have one child, $35$% have two child and $30$% have $3$ or more. Suppose that that the probability of having a boy or a girl is the same. If one family is chosen randomly, and $X$ is the number of boys and $Y$ the number of girls. Find the density function of $X,Y$.

This is what i was trying, but i'm not sure, for example 
$$f(1,0)=.2\times.5=..1$$
$$f(2,0))=.35\times.5\times.5$$

Comment: Your numbers are correct, I think you know how to do the problem.

Comment: Well, I sort of take it back. You know how to deal with families with $2$ or fewer children. But the information supplied does not allow us to compute for $X+Y\ge 3$.